# How to create a WebLogic Domain through REST Api

Tags: rest, api, weblogic

I'm looking for a way to only create a Weblogic Domain through REST Api.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Dan

Comment: You need a server (Admin Server) to receive your REST requests, and you need a domain to configure and start this server. Then, it's not possible. You can create a basic domain using WLST or the domain configuration wizzard, start the admin server and then, finish your configuration using the REST API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already have a Admin Server and a domain i just want to create other domain by API Request.

Comment: you can't, an admin server can only handle configuration of its own domain...